# Eclipse interface used in other Application

Tags: eclipse

I'm looking for some stuff that learn how use Eclipse IDE interface in my own application.
Someone know how? I couldn't find something abou it. Tips

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for the Eclipse Richt Client Platform. You might want to start here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_RCP_How-to

Comment: Yes, and building an RCP that is based on the IDE (if you need workspaces and projects, etc.) is possible, too.